# python user input for finding leap year not printing

Tags: python, if-statement, int, user-input

I am trying to create a function that accepts a users input and tries to figure out whether the year is a leap year and later also accept the users day of year (i.e. 355) and turns it into which day of the year it is (and output December, 10 2018). But for now I am not sure why it will not output whether the year is `True` or `False`. I tried to use the `int` parameter to change the user input from a string to a number but I am not sure if that is where I went wrong.

```
 user_year = input('Enter year: ')
    val = int(user_year)
    def leap_year(val):
        if val % 400 == 0:
            print ("True")
        if val % 100 == 0:
            print ("False")
        if val % 4 == 0:
            print ("True")
        else:
            print ("False")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only defining the function `leap_year` but you're never calling it, below is an example where it actually gets called:

```
user_year = input('Enter year: ')
val = int(user_year)

def leap_year(val):
    if val % 400 == 0:
        print ("True")
    if val % 100 == 0:
        print ("False")
    if val % 4 == 0:
        print ("True")
    else:
        print ("False")

leap_year(val)
```

Also your indentation is a bit off, which causes it to not compile in the first place, but that could also be an error while copying to Stackoverflow.